# Unique Rows based on Column

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to execute the MySQL query, I have 2 columns id and code, id is auto generated. What i tied is below. I am getting what I am trying to achieve. I tried too many query combination Unique, Distinct,etc.

```
Query: "SELECT DISTINCT(code) FROM table GROUP BY code ORDER BY id DESC;"
id  code
1   0000
2   0000
3   0001
4   0001
5   0001
6   0002
7   0003

What i am trying to do get

id  code
2   0000
5   0001
6   0002
7   0003
```

Comment: `GROUP BY id` or `DISTINCT id` should be what you want.

Comment: Do you want the **LAST** ID near the code? is that it?

Comment: no, may be i am not able to explain properly, we have 2 0000 code, so it should return the latest row of 0000 i-e result of id 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE id IN (SELECT MAX(id) FROM `table` GROUP BY `code` ORDER BY `id`)
```

For DESC order use this:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE id IN (SELECT MAX(id) FROM `table` GROUP BY `code`) ORDER BY `id` DESC
```

Comment: @Roger, I edited and used the `MAX` MySQL function to give the last id per code. Now it should give you exactly what you need.

Comment: Sorry @Dalai, forgot to mentioned i have one more column name but name  is not returning for example for id 2, it is returning the name of id 1.

Comment: So in short based on latest id and unique code, query should return result

Comment: Understood. In that case we must **FIRST** grab the ID and only then show the result. Look at my edit.

Comment: you are pro champ, Thanks, I want latest to come first to DESC is fine in last after order by clause?

Comment: Yes.

The max refers to the id as a number. so it doesn't matter how you sort it, it will pick the last id since it's Auto Incremental.

In fact - the order in the inner query is meaningless.